# Get last record in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

How can I SELECT the last row in a MySQL table using php?
I have 3 columns id(AI), longitude and latitude. 
DBName: fts
TableName: currentlocation

Thanks for the response guys, 
I have acquired right results by using such query
SELECT  longitude, latitude FROM currentlocation ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: ORDER BY should fulfill all your needs

Comment: quite a few ways actually; what did you try?

Comment: I would use Count() to find the number of rows. Then if your ids corresponds to rows, I would select the row with the id that equals count.

Comment: Or use Franz answer to Order by and then select the first row.

Comment: Or `WHERE id = MAX(id)` _Choices,Choices,Choices,Choices,Choices_ Or as a last resort, you could google it [Or read the MYSQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/). _Ooppps how silly of me, that will never do_

Comment: @RiggsFolly while you're editing: `Choises => Choices` ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- What would I do without my _Spolling Chicker_

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't know, you tell me *lol*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I would Spoll shot bodly

Comment: @RiggsFolly Care for an 18-hole at midnight on Halloween? It's going to be a full moon I think.

Comment: one has to wonder where the OP is in all this. You've been given comments an answers; the ball is in your court, *as it were*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have tried DESC and at first it doesn't gave right results, but after some amendments, its all right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following to the end of your query:

```
order by id desc limit 1
```

Reference:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: Well, the table doesn't *have* to have a primary key.  He can sort by whatever column(s) he wants.

Comment: @David he didn't mentioned about not using the primary key. Are you sure?

Comment: Nouman has mentioned that `id(AI)`, AI here means auto-incrementing and MySql generally has primary-key on id with auto-incrementing.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that any column(s) can be used in an `ORDER BY` clause.  The OP doesn't really specify how the data should be sorted.  One can infer that he wants it sorted by the `id` column, and one would likely be correct.  But that's not a requirement.  The concept of "last" changes with the sorting.

Comment: Just as @David said; the idea of "must be having a primary key" is irrelevant. It can be anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- that was an assumption thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @user6865936 You're welcome. I edited your answer accordingly with a reference link.

Comment: and also he was looking for PHP specifics :) lets wait for OP he could be sleeping.

Comment: Thanks Guys, issue is solved.

Comment: @Samundra Right about PK. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Following assumptions were made to answer the question.

- primary key is `id`
- row is sorted by `id` on descending order, last row always has highest value of id

The below code can be used to retrieve the last row using PHP.

```
<?php

class CurrentLocation {
    public $id;
    public $latitude;
    public $longitude;
}

$user  = 'root';
$pass  = '';
$dbh   = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fts', $user, $pass);
$query = "SELECT id, latitude, longitude FROM currentlocation ORDER BY id DESC";
$sth   = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchObject('CurrentLocation');
print_r($result);
```

Here, I am using PHP's `PDO` and it's `fetchObject` whose return maps to class `CurrentLocation`. For simplicity, instead of `fetchObject` one can also use `$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Please change `$user`, `$pass` to your MySql username, password and run the script. It should give you an output similar to the one below:

```
CurrentLocation Object
(
    [id] => 2
    [latitude] => 23.32
    [longitude] => 86.33
)
```

Please update your question, if you have any specific changes to be made here and then I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, issue is solved.